# Enable IBM MQ tracing in Azure durable function

Tags: configuration, azure-functions, ibm-mq, trace

I am trying to enable MQ client tracing in my Azure durable Function App (.NET 7, Isolated, on Windows), but I have not been very successful so far.

I am using IBMMQDotnetClient 9.3.3.

I have placed a mqclient.ini file in the root of the application, with the following contents:

```
MQDotnetTraceLevel=2
MQDotnetTracePath=C:home\mq_traces
MQDonetErrorPath=C:home\mq_traces_error
```

and created both directories on my function app file share in the corresponding storage account.
I cannot see any files being created in those directories.

How can I get tracing for this .NET client working inside an Azure function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Trace` stanza, like the following:

```
Trace:
   MQDotnetTraceLevel=2
   MQDotnetTracePath=C:home\mq_traces
   MQDonetErrorPath=C:home\mq_traces_error
```

This is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-tracing-mq-net-mqclientini).

Comment: Indeed, using a stanza is only mentioned, there is no actual sample available so I forgot to put it in there. Thanks

Comment: I agree it would be nice if they provided a sample.   You can provide feedback on any IBM doc page.